# how to upload image from android to mysql database where database fields are mime type and blob

Tags: php, android, mysql

**Table name:** `patronimage` in mysql database

```
borrowernumber  mimetype       imagefile

        1         image/png     [BLOB - 14.1 KiB]

        2         image/png     [BLOB - 35.6 KiB]
```

i want to insert image into this table through android

**Myserver code:**

```
<?php
 include 'connection.php';
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


        $borrower = "109"//$_POST['borrower'];
        $tempName= $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);

                      $query = "INSERT INTO `patronimage`(`borrowernumber`, `mimetype`, `imagefile`)VALUES('$borrower','{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$tempName}')";


                if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
 echo json_encode(array( "status" => "true","message" => "Successfully file added!") );


                }else{
                    echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Failed!") );
                }
}
?>
```

Android code: Android Code of multipart request:

**MainActivity.java**

```
 private void uploadImage(final Bitmap bitmap){

        VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, upload_URL,
                new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        Log.d("ressssssoo",new String(response.data));
                        rQueue.getCache().clear();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            jsonObject.toString().replace("\\\\","");

                            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("true")) {

                                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                                String url = "";
                                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    url = dataobj.optString("pathToFile");
                                }
                                Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {

            /*
             * If you want to add more parameters with the image
             * you can do it here
             * here we have only one parameter with the image
             * which is tags
             * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
               // params.put("tags", "ccccc");  add string parameters
                return params;
            }

            /*
             *pass files using below method
             * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                long imagename = System.currentTimeMillis();
                params.put("filename", new DataPart(imagename + ".png", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));
                return params;
            }
        };


        volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        rQueue.add(volleyMultipartRequest);
    }
```

**VolleyMultipartRequest.java**

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;


    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Custom method handle data payload.
     *
     * @return Map data part label with data byte
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    /**
     * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param params           string inputs collection
     * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse data into data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
     * @param data             loop through data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write string data into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param parameterName    name of input
     * @param parameterValue   value of input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Write data file into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
     * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
     * @param inputName        name of data input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    }

    class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;

        public DataPart() {
        }

        DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
        }

        String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        String getType() {
            return type;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to insert image above mentioned database table `patronimage` as blob file.

Thank You

Comment: For the backend part, you might want to refer here https://phppot.com/php/mysql-blob-using-php/ . Also you can check on php if your image is uploading properly to server
Please upvote if useful

Comment: No....yaar ..I know this technique how to insert image mime type blob in MySQL through html php...but I am trying to insert through android... unfortunately I didn't get solution..please tell me solution ...